# Selenium 4 with Java: Mocking/stubbing network requests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mocking, cypress, stubbing

Is there a more or less comprehensive guide on how to mock/stub network requests in Selinum 4? This is, as I see it, the main strength of Cypress (as well as ease of access for frontend developers), and I've been waiting to see a smooth way to do this with Selenium without lots of extra software.

In cypress, I can just open the developer -> network tab in Chrome, copy the request, and create a route. Then voilla! - the page can be opened with all the data in place as if the page had been accessed and data sent to the backend manually.

Anyone know how/where to get started with this in Selenium 4? Or have I misunderstood completely when thinking that this is a new feature?

Comment: Maybe [Selenium-Interceptor](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Interceptor) helps you as a starting point

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at that (y)

Comment: It's Python, though. Not very knowledgeable about that :-/

Comment: Which language are you using? You haven't mentioned it

Comment: Sorry, forgot that. Java or Kotlin.

Comment: I am searching for the same thing, but with Javascript instead of Java. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium's BiDirectional API seems to be what you're after. They have a network interception example in both Java and Kotlin on their website. Hopefully that's enough to get you started.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/bidi_api/#network-interception

Comment: It seems like the link is broken and not valid anymore.

Comment: @StSch thanks. updated the link to the latest documentation

Comment: documentation is really terrible. I need to do it in Javascript, but docs are empty. Any chance someone knows how to do it or where to start?